# C++ simple interactive shell prompt hiding when redirecting input

Tags: c++, shell, prompt

I am writing a simple interactive shell program in C++. It should work simalary to `sh` or `bash`.

Program looks like this (simplified as much as possible):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string command;

    while (1){
        std::cout << "prompt> ";
        std::getline(std::cin, command);
        std::cout << command << std::endl;
        if (command.compare("exit") == 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works as desired with human interaction. It prompts, user writes command, shell executes it.

However, if I run shell like this `./shell < test.in` (redirect input) it produces output with shell prompts like this:

```
prompt> echo "something"
prompt> echo "something else"
prompt> date
prompt> exit
```

It does produce correct output (just output input string in this case) but it is 'poluted' with prompts.

Is there some rather simple way to get rid of it (if I do the same with e.g. `bash` there is no prompt in output) when redirecting input?
Thank you in advance

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running on a *NIX-type system, you can (and should) use `isatty` to test whether stdin is connected to a tty (interactive terminal).

Something like this will work:

```
if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    std::cout << "prompt> ";
} // else: no prompt for non-interactive sessions
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed by [cheers-and-hth-alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) works for me. Thanks

Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    std::string command;

    while (1){
        if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)){
            std::cout << "prompt> ";
        }
        std::getline(std::cin, command);
        std::cout << command << std::endl;
        if (command.compare("exit") == 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```